# Suppose that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Tags: probability

Can I get a hint on how to start this problem?

Suppose that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent with marginal pdfs, $f_X(x) = 2x$, $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f_Y(y)= 3y^2$, $0 \le y \le 1$ Find $P(Y < X)$.

I'm at a total loss of what I even need to do here. I don't even know what I should tag this question with.

Thanks.

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=2x\cdot3y^2$, $x,y\in[0,1]$. Now, it suffices to write $P(Y<X)=\int_0^1\int_0^11_{y<x}f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the previous comments points out,
$$
\begin{align}
P(Y<X)
=&\int1_{y<x}f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)dxdy\\
=&\int_0^1\int_0^x6xy^2dydx\\
=&\int_0^12x^4dx\\
=&\int_0^12x^4dx\\
=&\frac{2}{5}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

First calculate the joint density, $(2x)(3y^2)$ over the obvious square, $0$ elsewhere.

Draw the square, and draw the line $y=x$. Let $D$ be the part of the square below the line. We want the probability $(X,Y)$ lands in $D$. This is
$$\iint_D (2x)(3y^2)\,dx\,dy.$$